# laplace equation $L^p$ estimate

Tags: partial-differential-equations, regularity-theory-of-pdes

Take a look at the inhomogeneous Laplace equation on a ball $B$:

\begin{cases}
- \Delta f = c\varphi, &\text{in } B \\
f = 0, & \text{on } \partial B
\end{cases}

where $\varphi$ is Lipschitz and $c > 0$. (This is linked to another [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2667257/sup-bounded-by-average) of mine.)

Now, how do I get the estimate:

$$\sup_{B_{1/2}} f \leq \bigg( \int_B (c\varphi)^p \bigg)^\frac 1p$$

As always, thanks for any help!

Comment: Is $p$ arbitrary?

Comment: it should be $p > \frac n 2$

Comment: i know how it works now! first i was so confused by this estimate... basically you get it from the representation formula of solutions on the ball, and then you can improve the $L^p$ estimate (for higher $p$) with the Moser technique.

Comment: You may consider writing an answer to your own question, which would help others who come across this question in the future.

Comment: i will, once i have some time!